# CSS картинка через ::before

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Помогите сделать так чтобы картинка была видна и не загораживалась текстом.

Вот так надо 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.clear-sort .btn--clear {
  border: 1px solid #ece8e3;
  background: transparent;
  color: #c8c4bf;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.clear-sort .btn--clear::before {
  content: "";
  background: url('https://forums.drom.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=3768838&d=1320973864') no-repeat 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear-sort">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn--clear">Tühjenda filtrid</button>
</div>
```

Comment: зачем там position:absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, всем спасибо за ответы.
Во-вторых, вариант Дмитрия Мирошниченко был точнее.

Стоит при изменении текста тоже учитывать картинку.

На картинке ответ Ильи Шишлачева:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И Дмитрия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге код:

```
.brands-detail .clear-sort .btn--clear{
    border: 1px solid #ece8e3;
    background: transparent;
    color: #c8c4bf;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 210px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 7px;
    position: relative;
}
.brands-detail .clear-sort .btn--clear::before{
      content: "";
  background: url('../images/base/clear.png') no-repeat 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй для `::before` так:

```
.clear-sort .btn--clear::before{
  content: "";
  background: url('../images/base/clear.png') no-repeat 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.clear-sort .btn-clear {
  border: 1px solid #ece8e3;
  background: transparent;
  color: #c8c4bf;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.clear-sort .btn-clear::before {
  content: "";
  background: url('../images/base/clear.png') no-repeat 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="clear-sort">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">Tühjenda filtrid</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
  background:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
button:before{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 1em  0 0;
  width:1.3em;
  height:1.3em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  background:url(http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-60eade7f184e696a79fa2ff1e81c851d.png) no-repeat center/contain;
}
```

```html
<button>Tühjenda filtrid</button>
```